# What is the Time complexity of this Algorithm using AVL tree and Binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Consider the following algorithm that sorts a list of n elements by using a binary search tree:

```
initialise t to be an empty binary search tree
for each element x in the list,
  add x to t
while t is not empty,
  remove and print the smallest element of t
```

What is the worst-case time complexity of this algorithm, if the tree is
implemented using:

a) an ordinary binary search tree?
b) an AVL tree?

My Solution: What i think the solution would be, for AVL tree: O(Log N) and for BST it would be O(N)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general programming concepts, not code-specific issues. It is a better fit for Programmers SE.

Comment: This question is related to data Structures, which I'am currently studying.

Comment: @keyser I did research and I got answer from my research, but i'm not sure of it.

Comment: In my opinion it would take (N) times to traverse the BST (worst-case) to find minimum, But in AVL trees its already balanced so it would only take log (n) to find the minimum, because of the rotations

Comment: Thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The worst case for insertions/deletions for these trees are `O(n)` for BST's and `O(log(n))` for AVL's.

If the list is of length `n` you do `n` insertions and `n` deletions, which means we get `O(n^2)` with BST's and `O(nlog(n))` with AVL's.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity for all BST is `O(h)`, where `h` is the height of BST. if the list contains `n` elements the time complexity will be `O(n)` because, it will perform   `n insertions and deletions`.While AVL is a self-balancing binary search tree, the height is `O(logn)`, so time complexity for insertion and deletion will be `O(logn)`.